# LISTAGG equivalent in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, string-aggregation

I'm having problems converting this from Oracle to PostgreSQL. I've tried using STRING_AGG, but i'm not having any success. I believe there's also an issue with REGEXP_REPLACE. Can someone help?

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(
    LISTAGG(column_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_name), 
    '([^,]+)(,\1)*(,|$)', 
    '\1\3'
)
```

Comment: `STRING_AGG(column_name, ',' ORDER BY column_name)` should work for the `listagg`/`string_agg` switch.

Comment: Can you share some sample data/desired results for the regex?

Comment: Looks like you might be trying to use regex to eliminate dupes as well...  you can use `distinct column_name` to handle that.

Comment: Thanks Hambone, I'll give that a try.

Comment: JNevill, Thanks. That works perfectly! Unfortunately, I can't share data, but in the future, I'll mock up some test data to post with my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want something like this:

```
string_agg(DISTINCT column_name, ',' ORDER BY column_name)
```

Comment: is there any way to order by a different column when wer are using string_agg?

Comment: @Agent47 Yes, that is no problem.